# How to deal with the errors when installing natcap.invest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pip, gdal

I try to install natcap.invest package in order to do some research using the InVEST model. But when I use pip to install it, lots of errors occur in the cmd window(like the message below). I don't know how to deal with these problems. I'm very thankful if there's anyone who can help me with this problem.

These are the message after I type "pip install natcap.invest":

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I recommend checking the logs for the full output, as the console says in your last image. Also, please just put the relevant console output into the question. People aren't going to want to click through half a dozen pictures of your console to figure out the issue.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth Thanks a lot. But I don't know which section is relevant to this question because all of these errors occured after I typed Enter in the console.

Comment: that log file described will hold some hint as to why the package wasn't able to install. it looks like it was most of the way through the install before it broke.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved this problem.
Maybe it's due to the GDAL package.
I try to download GDAL3.2.3 via [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal), and "pip install natcap.invest", and then it works.